# How do I print out a the results of a hash key using regex

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to search for a hash key using re.search and print the result.

I've tried a number of search criteria but it returns nothing.

The search string:

```
FLASH\hashval.key        234      -A7B865C48E-
```

The string for retrieving the value I need

```
match = re.search(r'^FLASH\\hashval.key.+\s+(\-\w+\-)\s+', line)
```

The code snippet

```py
    def _test_hashval_key(self):
        '''
        Verify that the hashval.key is correct in the DRP.
        '''
        tid = 'HashVal'
        cmd = 'drpmrs dev=/dev/ro2 filelist'
        sts, out = runcmd(cmd)
        fnd = False
        for line in out.split('\n'):
            line = line.strip()
            #FLASH\hashval.key        234      -A7B865C48E-
            match = re.search(r'^FLASH\\hashval.key.+\s+(\-\w+\-)\s+', line)
            if match:
                hash = match.group(1)
                print hash()
                fnd = True
                val = -A7B865C48E-
                val1 = -EDA6384F89-
                val2 = -BF384513DC-
                if val == hash:
                    self._passed(tid, 'hashval.key sys: %s'  % (hash))
                if val1 == hash:
                    self._passed(tid, 'hashval.key prd: %s'  % (hash))
                if val2 == hash:
                    self._passed(tid, 'hashval.key crp: %s'  % (hash))
            if not match:
                self._failed(tid, 'hashval.key not found')
```

This what I'd like to display as an example:

```py
Test:14 HashVal: crp -A7B865C48E-
```

Comment: Just remove the `\s+` at the end, it will fail to match if there isn't some space at the end of the string.

Comment: `hash()` unknown and `val = -A7B865C48E-` `val1 = -EDA6384F89-` `val2 = -BF384513DC-` are all illegal python ...

Comment: Thank you Thierry and Patrick. I removed the \s+, but it still does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the correct regex

`match = re.search(r'^FLASH\\hashval.key.\s+(.*)\-', line)`